# How to determine if an equation represents a cubic spline?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, spline

Given the equation

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       2x^3+x^2+4x+5 & : 0 \le x \le 1\\
       (x-1)^3 + 7(x-1)^2 + 12(x-1)+12 & : 1 \le x \le 2
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

What is the process used to determine if this represents a cubic spline?

It's obviously a piecewise interpolation, and the second function simplifies, so perhaps it's better to write like:

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       2x^3+x^2+4x+5 & : 0 \le x \le 1\\
       x^3+4x^2+x+6 & : 1 \le x \le 2
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both expression are obviously cubic.  If they both have the same value *and the same first and second derivatives* at $x=1$, your set of expressions fits the definition of a cubic spline.  A pretty simple spline, but there it is.

Comment: so you're saying that the derivative of both functions should the same thing (i.e. $6x^2 + 2x + 4$ and $3x^2+8x+1$, and they should give the same value when evaluated at x=1? They both give 12 when x = 1.

Comment: Yes, the derivatives of both functions should be the same value at x=1.  (And the values of the functions should also be the same at x=1.)

Comment: For a cubic spline you also need the continuity of the second derivative.

Comment: @jaska  Whoops!  LutzL is right!  I forgot!  You have to check the second derivative too.